# How do I fix a clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn c++ but I cannot run a basic HelloWorld program.

Im am receiving an error saying 
[Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC5OC.png)

This is the code.

```
 #include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you building your code / invoking the compiler (*exactly*)? And please, don't post images of stuff that should really be *text*.

Comment: Have you tried using the `-v` to see the invocation?

Comment: Best guess is that clang was installed, but no standard library. If Windows, llvm is not sufficient. You need to install the VS C++ build tools.

Comment: Did you try searching here for `[clang] undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 main`?

Answer (score -1):

Nihal, If you are doing this work for a course, you should search/ask for instructions on how to successfully install the required environment.

If you are self-teaching, you might consider starting with an environment like repl.it (https://repl.it/). It's online, it's free, and if you ask it to create a C++ project for you, you will have everything you need to start with.

I use repl.it to teach my college-level C++ course. It works well for all the basic stuff, including file I/O.